# Sitecore Static binding With Placeholder

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I have a requirement where I am rendering placeholder dynamically in a view and I wanted to add some of the existing components in that placeholder. So the code goes something like below.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= Columns; i++)
{
      @Html.Sitecore().DynamicPlaceholder("ec-" + i)
}
```

Then in another loop I am adding the component

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering(ComponentItemId, new { DataSource = ds.Id })
```

There is no option to pass placeholder name here as it's static binding.

But what if I wanted pass the placeholder name and wanted to render the component in that placeholder and I want to do it from code not from experience editor like manually adding components to page.

I have the dynamic placeholder id generated at runtime.
Please suggest me if this is something possible through some customization

So like in runtime how can we add a component to a page in to a specific placeholder if we know the placeholder along with data source

Comment: So every time the page ran you'd have to check if the component has been added to the placeholder already?

Comment: no . The idea is to make the components selectable in Experience editor.